# send mail as hostname@example.com instead of root@example.com

Tags: email, postfix, exim

I'm trying to have emails sent as hostname@example.com. Hostname being the name of the machine. This way I know which machines are sending me alerts.

Running postfix on Debian 8. I created a generic file and listed

```
root@example.com    hostname@example.com
```

Ran postmap generic and restarted postfix after modifying the main.cf to reference the generic file.

When I send mail as root, it still arrives as root@example.com on the postfix server.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

On a non-postfix machine, just running exim4, emails are sent as hostname@example.com but with the root in the from field (name). How can I remove the name? Do I just remove the name root from /etc/passwd ?

Comment: Please add the output of `postconf -n` so we can see what your Postfix configuration actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you have to do is to add appropriate line to the `begin rewrite` section of exim's config:

```
begin rewrite
  . . . . . .
  root@example.com    hostname@example.com    Ffrsw
```

Here flags `Ffrs` defines what headers will be rewrited:

- F = ENVELOPE FROM
- f = FROM
- r = RETURN-PATH
- s = SENDER
- w = Complete rewrite, i.e. `<Root> root@example.com` become `hostname@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

For Postfix,

```
echo 'root hostname@example.com' >> /etc/postfix/generic
postmap /etc/postfix/generic
postconf -e smtp_generic_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/generic
service postfix restart
```

just maps the source name to the email address you want it to come from.